# Is there an API that takes a location and finds its coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, html, google-maps-api-3

Is there an API out there that will take a name of a location (building name, city name, etc) and find its coordinates on a map?  I looked at the google maps api and it looks like it requires you to use the actual maps.google map.  I'm trying to create my own map, but find the coordinates of certain locations using an api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's called geocoding and you can use Google maps API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/